# Getting best possible allocation out of wish list

Tags: php, mysql, excel, ms-access

First of all: I am sorry for my bad english and hope that you can understand my request.

In my school the graduates have to pick a topic for a thesis in the final year. Each student chooses a tutor from one subject area to help them.

**Starting position**

- Each student must specify exactly three wishes, which are sorted in descending order of preference. Example: 1. Mr. Jobs / 2. Mr. Gates / 3. Mr. Musk
- Each tutor may supervise a maximum of three students

How can I make sure that as many students as possible get their first wish? Of the remaining students, as many as possible should get the second wish, the rest the third wish.

Which programming language is best suited for this problem: PHP, Access, Excel?

So far, we sort the wishes by hand, in a process that takes several hours. Sometimes days.

We would like to automate this process. Many thanks for every idea, every approach, every hint.

Ideal case: We have a list that shows the tutors and the students assigned to them.

**Example:**

- Mr. Jobs -> Stacy, Carl, Melody
- Mr. Gates -> William, Eric, Charlott
- Mr. Musk -> Anthony, Sarah, Nelly

Best wishes, stay healthy!

Comment: There is no dependence to any programming language, it just need an algorithm and I'm sure there is an algorithm in real world for these type of problems. Something like `knapsack`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this piece of php does it if you format the input arrays right..

$preferencesOfStudents is the student, with their prefered teachers in order.

```
function shuffle_assoc($list) { 
  if (!is_array($list)) return $list; 

  $keys = array_keys($list); 
  shuffle($keys); 
  $random = array(); 
  foreach ($keys as $key) { 
    $random[$key] = $list[$key]; 
  }
  return $random; 
} 
$preferencesOfStudents = [
  'students' => [
      'Stacy' => ['Mr Jobs','Mr Gates','Mr Musk'],
      'Carl' => ['Mr Jobs','Mr Gates','Mr Musk'],
      'Melody' => ['Mr Jobs','Mr Musk','Mr Gates'],
      'William' => ['Mr Musk','Mr Gates','Mr Jobs'],
      'Eric' => ['Mr Gates','Mr Jobs','Mr Musk'],
      'Charlott' => ['Mr Jobs','Mr Gates','Mr Musk'],
      'Anthony' => ['Mr Gates','Mr Musk','Mr Jobs'],
      'Sarah' => ['Mr Gates','Mr Jobs','Mr Musk'],
      'Nelly' => ['Mr Gates','Mr Musk','Mr Jobs']
    ]
];

// 1 = Jobs, 2 = Gates, 3 = Musk
$teachers = [
  'Mr Jobs' => [],
  'Mr Gates' => [],
  'Mr Musk' => []
];
$randomstudentsarray = shuffle_assoc($preferencesOfStudents['students']);
//print_r($randomstudentsarray);
foreach($randomstudentsarray as $name => $student){
  if(count($teachers[$student[0]]) < 3){
    $teachers[$student[0]][] = $name;
  } elseif(count($teachers[$student[1]]) < 3) {
    $teachers[$student[1]][] = $name;  
  } else {
    $teachers[$student[2]][] = $name;
  }
  
  
}

print_r($teachers);
```

Comment: thx. I will try this later. then let you know if it worked.

Comment: It works. Thank you very much. Unfortunately, I forgot to mention a few things, but I'll try to bite through it.

Comment: Maybe you can help? https://stackoverflow.com/q/63225518/4421892