# Extend array with additional requirements

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am new to PHP, but I do my best. Please be patient with me. :)

Yesterday I already asked a similar question, but today I have to extend it.

**Initial Situation**

In my school the graduates have to pick a topic for a thesis in the final year. Each student chooses a tutor from one subject area to help them.

**Starting position**

- Each student must specify exactly three wishes, which are sorted in
  descending order of preference. Example: Stacy chooses Mr. Jobs in
  Design as her first wish, Carl also chooses Mr. Jobs as his first
  wish, but in usability. William selects Mr. Gates in Computer Science
  as his first choice, Charlott selects Mr. Gates in Biology as his
  first choice.
- Each tutor may supervise a maximum of three students.
- Each teacher can be selected in up to two subjects. So Mr Jobs could
  be chosen in design and usability, Mr Gates in computer science and
  biology, Mr Musk in physics and geography.

**Example of possible elections:**

```
Mr. Jobs -> Stacy (Design), Carl (Usability), Melody (Design)
Mr. Gates -> William (Computer Science), Eric (Biology), Charlott (Biology)
Mr. Musk -> Anthony (Physics), Sarah (Physics), Nelly (Geography)
```

**Final Questions**

- How can I make sure that as many students as possible get their first
  wish? Of the remaining students, as many as possible should get the
  second wish, the rest the third wish. (done? do you have tipps?)
- How can I extend the following script so that the different subjects
  of my colleagues are taken into account, but no one supervises more
  than 3 students?
- How can I tell the script to also output whether the assignment is
  the first wish, second wish or third wish?

User **Rustyjim** helped me yesterday with the following script. Thanks again!

Best wishes, stay healthy!

**Script so far**

```
function shuffle_assoc($list) {
    if (!is_array($list)) return $list;
    $keys = array_keys($list);
    shuffle($keys);
    $random = array();
    foreach ($keys as $key) {
        $random[$key] = $list[$key];
    }
    return $random;
}
$preferencesOfStudents = [
    'students' => [
        'Stacy' => ['Mr Jobs','Mr Gates','Mr Musk'],
        'Carl' => ['Mr Jobs','Mr Gates','Mr Musk'],
        'Melody' => ['Mr Jobs','Mr Musk','Mr Gates'],
        'William' => ['Mr Musk','Mr Gates','Mr Jobs'],
        'Eric' => ['Mr Gates','Mr Jobs','Mr Musk'],
        'Charlott' => ['Mr Jobs','Mr Gates','Mr Musk'],
        'Anthony' => ['Mr Gates','Mr Musk','Mr Jobs'],
        'Sarah' => ['Mr Gates','Mr Jobs','Mr Musk'],
        'Nelly' => ['Mr Gates','Mr Musk','Mr Jobs']
    ]
];
// 1 = Jobs, 2 = Gates, 3 = Musk
$teachers = [
    'Mr Jobs' => [],
    'Mr Gates' => [],
    'Mr Musk' => []
];
$randomStudentsArray = shuffle_assoc($preferencesOfStudents['students']);
//print_r($randomStudentsArray);
foreach($randomStudentsArray as $name => $student){
    if(count($teachers[$student[0]]) < 3){
        $teachers[$student[0]][] = $name;
    } elseif(count($teachers[$student[1]]) < 3) {
        $teachers[$student[1]][] = $name;
    } else {
        $teachers[$student[2]][] = $name;
    }
}
print_r($teachers);
```

Comment: will take a look tonight after work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: This works? Hope to help!

If there is a maximum of 2 specializations there is a problem though: not all students can be assigned sometimes.

But is tries as well as it can, and random, so if it does not give a nice output, just try again.

```
   <?php
function shuffle_assoc($list) {
    if (!is_array($list)) return $list;
    $keys = array_keys($list);
    shuffle($keys);
    $random = array();
    foreach ($keys as $key) {
        $random[$key] = $list[$key];
    }
    return $random;
}
function searchForId($id, $array) {
    foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
        if ($val['specializations'] === $id) {
            return $key;
        }
    }
    return null;
 }
$preferencesOfStudents = [
    'students' => [
        'Stacy' => ['Mr Jobs','Mr Gates','Mr Musk', 'Biology'],
        'Carl' => ['Mr Jobs','Mr Gates','Mr Musk', 'Design'],
        'Melody' => ['Mr Bezos','Mr Musk','Mr Gates', 'Usability'],
        'William' => ['Mr Musk','Mr Gates','Mr Jobs', 'Computer Science'],
        'Eric' => ['Mr Gates','Mr Jobs','Mr Musk', 'Physics'],
        'Charlott' => ['Mr Jobs','Mr Gates','Mr Musk', 'Geography'],
        'Anthony' => ['Mr Gates','Mr Musk','Mr Jobs', 'Geography'],
        'Sarah' => ['Mr Gates','Mr Jobs','Mr Musk', 'Design'],
        'Nelly' => ['Mr Gates','Mr Musk','Mr Jobs', 'Usability'],
        'Connor' => ['Mr Gates','Mr Jobs','Mr Musk', 'Physics'],
        'Frodo' => ['Mr Gates','Mr Musk','Mr Jobs', 'Computer Science'],
        'Achmed' => ['Mr Gates','Mr Jobs','Mr Musk', 'Computer Science']
    ]
];

$teachers = [
    'Mr Jobs' => [
        'students' => [],
        'specializations' => []
    ],
    'Mr Gates' => [
        'students' => [],
        'specializations' => []
    ],
    'Mr Musk' => [
        'students' => [],
        'specializations' => []
    ],
    'Mr Bezos' => [
        'students' => [],
        'specializations' => []
    ]
];
$unassigned = [];
$randomStudentsArray = shuffle_assoc($preferencesOfStudents['students']);
/*assign students to prefered spots randomly*/
foreach($randomStudentsArray as $name => $student){
    foreach ($teachers as $teacherName => $array) {
        if (in_array($student[3],$array['specializations'])) {
            $teachers[$teacherName]['students'][] = $name." (because of specialization) (".$student[3].")";
            $teachers[$teacherName]['specializations'][] = $student[3];
            break;
        }
    }
    if(count($teachers[$student[0]]['students']) < 5 && count($teachers[$student[0]]['specializations']) < 2){   
        $teachers[$student[0]]['students'][] = $name." (first choice) (".$student[3].")";
        $teachers[$student[0]]['specializations'][] = $student[3]; 
    } elseif(count($teachers[$student[1]]['students']) < 5 && count($teachers[$student[1]]['specializations']) < 2) {
        $teachers[$student[1]]['students'][] = $name." (second choice) (".$student[3].")";
        $teachers[$student[1]]['specializations'][] = $student[3];
    } elseif(count($teachers[$student[2]]['students']) < 5 && count($teachers[$student[2]]['specializations']) < 2)  {
        $teachers[$student[2]]['students'][] = $name." (third choice) (".$student[3].")";
        $teachers[$student[2]]['specializations'][] = $student[3];
    } else {
        $unassigned[$name] = $student;
    }
}
/*assign unassigned student to free spots*/
foreach($unassigned as $name => $student){
    foreach($teachers as $teacherName => $listOfStudents){
        if(count($listOfStudents['students']) < 5 && count($listOfStudents['specializations']) < 2){
            $teachers[$teacherName]['students'][] = $name." (none of prefered choices) (".$student[3].")";
            $teachers[$teacherName]['specializations'][] = $student[3];
        }
    }
}
print_r($teachers);
```

EDIT2:

```
<?php
function shuffle_assoc($list) {
    if (!is_array($list)) return $list;
    $keys = array_keys($list);
    shuffle($keys);
    $random = array();
    foreach ($keys as $key) {
        $random[$key] = $list[$key];
    }
    return $random;
}
function searchForId($id, $array) {
    foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
        if ($val['specializations'] === $id) {
            return $key;
        }
    }
    return null;
 }
$preferencesOfStudents = [
    'students' => [
        'Stacy' => ['Mr Jobs','Mr Gates','Mr Musk', 'Biology'],
        'Carl' => ['Mr Jobs','Mr Gates','Mr Musk', 'Design'],
        'Melody' => ['Mr Bezos','Mr Musk','Mr Gates', 'Usability'],
        'William' => ['Mr Musk','Mr Gates','Mr Jobs', 'Computer Science'],
        'Eric' => ['Mr Gates','Mr Jobs','Mr Musk', 'Physics'],
        'Charlott' => ['Mr Jobs','Mr Gates','Mr Musk', 'Geography'],
        'Anthony' => ['Mr Gates','Mr Musk','Mr Jobs', 'Geography'],
        'Sarah' => ['Mr Gates','Mr Jobs','Mr Musk', 'Design'],
        'Nelly' => ['Mr Gates','Mr Musk','Mr Jobs', 'Usability'],
        'Connor' => ['Mr Gates','Mr Jobs','Mr Musk', 'Physics'],
        'Frodo' => ['Mr Gates','Mr Musk','Mr Jobs', 'Computer Science'],
        'Achmed' => ['Mr Gates','Mr Jobs','Mr Musk', 'Computer Science']
    ]
];

$teachers = [
    'Mr Jobs' => [
        'students' => [],
        'specializations' => ['Biology', 'Design']
    ],
    'Mr Gates' => [
        'students' => [],
        'specializations' => ['Computer Science', 'Usability']
    ],
    'Mr Musk' => [
        'students' => [],
        'specializations' => ['Physics', 'Geography']
    ],
    'Mr Bezos' => [
        'students' => [],
        'specializations' => ['Usability', 'Biology']
    ]
];
$unassigned = [];
$randomStudentsArray = shuffle_assoc($preferencesOfStudents['students']);
/*assign students to prefered spots randomly*/
foreach($randomStudentsArray as $name => $student){
    if(count($teachers[$student[0]]['students']) < 5 && in_array($student[3],$teachers[$student[0]]['specializations'])){   
        $teachers[$student[0]]['students'][] = $name." (first choice) (".$student[3].")";
    } elseif(count($teachers[$student[1]]['students']) < 5 && in_array($student[3],$teachers[$student[1]]['specializations'])) {
        $teachers[$student[1]]['students'][] = $name." (second choice) (".$student[3].")";
    } elseif(count($teachers[$student[2]]['students']) < 5 && in_array($student[3],$teachers[$student[2]]['specializations']))  {
        $teachers[$student[2]]['students'][] = $name." (third choice) (".$student[3].")";
    } else {
        $unassigned[$name] = $student;
    }
}
/*assign unassigned student to free spots*/
foreach($unassigned as $name => $student){
    foreach($teachers as $teacherName => $listOfStudents){
        if(count($listOfStudents['students']) < 5 && count($listOfStudents['specializations']) < 2 && in_array($student[3],$teachers[$teacherName]['specializations'])){
            $teachers[$teacherName]['students'][] = $name." (none of prefered choices) (".$student[3].")";
        }
    }
}
print_r($teachers);
```

EDIT3:

```
<?php
function shuffle_assoc($list) {
    if (!is_array($list)) return $list;
    $keys = array_keys($list);
    shuffle($keys);
    $random = array();
    foreach ($keys as $key) {
        $random[$key] = $list[$key];
    }
    return $random;
}
function searchForId($id, $array) {
    foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
        if ($val['specializations'] === $id) {
            return $key;
        }
    }
    return null;
 }
$preferencesOfStudents = [
    'students' => [
        'Stacy' => ['Mr Jobs','Mr Gates','Mr Musk', 'Biology', 'Usability'],
        'Carl' => ['Mr Jobs','Mr Gates','Mr Musk', 'Design', 'Physics'],
        'Melody' => ['Mr Bezos','Mr Musk','Mr Gates', 'Usability', 'Physics'],
        'William' => ['Mr Musk','Mr Gates','Mr Jobs', 'Computer Science', 'Usability'],
        'Eric' => ['Mr Gates','Mr Jobs','Mr Musk', 'Physics', 'Design'],
        'Charlott' => ['Mr Bezos','Mr Gates','Mr Musk', 'Geography', 'Design'],
        'Anthony' => ['Mr Gates','Mr Musk','Mr Jobs', 'Geography', 'Computer Science'],
        'Sarah' => ['Mr Bezos','Mr Jobs','Mr Musk', 'Design', 'Physics'],
        'Nelly' => ['Mr Gates','Mr Musk','Mr Jobs', 'Usability', 'Design'],
        'Connor' => ['Mr Gates','Mr Bezos','Mr Musk', 'Physics', 'Usability'],
        'Frodo' => ['Mr Gates','Mr Musk','Mr Jobs', 'Computer Science', 'Geography'],
        'Achmed' => ['Mr Gates','Mr Jobs','Mr Musk', 'Computer Science', 'Geography'],
        'Charlie' => ['Mr Bezos','Mr Musk','Mr Gates', 'Usability', 'Physics'],
        'India' => ['Mr Musk','Mr Gates','Mr Jobs', 'Computer Science', 'Usability'],
        'Lima' => ['Mr Gates','Mr Jobs','Mr Musk', 'Physics', 'Design'],
        'Mike' => ['Mr Jobs','Mr Gates','Mr Musk', 'Geography', 'Design'],
        'Oscar' => ['Mr Gates','Mr Musk','Mr Jobs', 'Usability', 'Computer Science'],
        'Quentin' => ['Mr Gates','Mr Jobs','Mr Musk', 'Design', 'Physics'],
        'Sam' => ['Mr Gates','Mr Musk','Mr Jobs', 'Usability', 'Design'],
        'Victor' => ['Mr Gates','Mr Jobs','Mr Musk', 'Physics', 'Usability'],
        'Zach' => ['Mr Gates','Mr Musk','Mr Jobs', 'Computer Science', 'Geography'],
        'Arya' => ['Mr Gates','Mr Jobs','Mr Musk', 'Computer Science', 'Geography']
    ]
];

$teachers = [
    'Mr Jobs' => [
        'students' => [],
        'specializations' => ['Biology', 'Design']
    ],
    'Mr Gates' => [
        'students' => [],
        'specializations' => ['Computer Science', 'Usability']
    ],
    'Mr Musk' => [
        'students' => [],
        'specializations' => ['Physics', 'Geography']
    ],
    'Mr Bezos' => [
        'students' => [],
        'specializations' => ['Usability', 'Biology']
    ]
];
$unassigned = [];
$randomStudentsArray = shuffle_assoc($preferencesOfStudents['students']);
/*assign students to prefered spots randomly*/
foreach($randomStudentsArray as $name => $student){
    if(count($teachers[$student[0]]['students']) < 5 && (in_array($student[3],$teachers[$student[0]]['specializations']) || in_array($student[3],$teachers[$student[0]]['specializations']))){   
        $teachers[$student[0]]['students'][] = $name." (first choice) (".$student[3].")";
    } elseif(count($teachers[$student[1]]['students']) < 5 && (in_array($student[3],$teachers[$student[1]]['specializations']) || in_array($student[3],$teachers[$student[0]]['specializations']))) {
        $teachers[$student[1]]['students'][] = $name." (second choice) (".$student[3].")";
    } elseif(count($teachers[$student[2]]['students']) < 5 && (in_array($student[3],$teachers[$student[2]]['specializations']) || in_array($student[3],$teachers[$student[0]]['specializations'])))  {
        $teachers[$student[2]]['students'][] = $name." (third choice) (".$student[3].")";
    } else {
        $unassigned[$name] = $student;
    }
}
/*assign unassigned student to free spots*/
foreach($unassigned as $name => $student){
    foreach($teachers as $teacherName => $listOfStudents){
        if(count($listOfStudents['students']) < 5 && count($listOfStudents['specializations']) < 2 && ( in_array($student[3],$teachers[$teacherName]['specializations']) || in_array($student[4],$teachers[$teacherName]['specializations']) )){
            $teachers[$teacherName]['students'][] = $name." (none of prefered choices) (".$student[3].")";
        }
    }
}
print_r($teachers);
```

Comment: Try this out please I will help with the subjects part just explain that abit more please :)

Comment: Regarding the subjects: It is possible that a teacher has two courses per year. Nevertheless, he/she may be loaded with a maximum of 5 papers. Is this explanation better?

Comment: So each student had a subject chosen? Then a teacher can do 2 subjects maximum? But what do you mean with 5 papers :)?

Comment: Each student must write a paper in one subject. A teacher can have a maximum of two courses in one year. The maximum number of essays a teacher may supervise is five. The fact that he/she may have two courses does not increase the maximum number of essays he/she may supervise to ten.

Comment: will try to make that for you later on!

Comment: Ok I changed the code! Hope it is good for your purpose

Comment: It's working. Thanks! But there is one thing I seem to have been unclear about: A teacher can have two different courses in one year. So Mr Jobs can have one course Design and one course Usability.

So the teachers can also only be selected in the subjects they teach.

Mr Jobs: Design and Usability - 
Mr Gates: Computer Science and Biology - 
Mr Musk: Physics and geography - 
Mr Bezos: Finance and export.

Excuse me, but I think this time it's clear?

Very good job! I am so grateful! I'm really learning a lot from your scripts!

Comment: Fine! :) One last thing: Is it possible to modify the script so that the students can choose from several teachers? I mean: Sarahs first wish is Mr Jobs with Design, her second wish is Mr Musk with physics.?

Comment: ok EDIT3 makes the students have 2 choices for a subject

Comment: thanks! it works perfect! now I just have to read the code and learn :)